# upgrade umbraco from 4.5.2 to 4.11.10

Tags: umbraco, upgrade

Can you please guide me through updating Umbraco from version `4.5.2` to version `4.11.10`(or best version in `4.11.xx`)..

Custom changes i currently have in my website:

1. Add 2 new areas to `config/Dashboard.config` to display custom usercontrols(these areas are displayed in `content` section)
2. Custom usercontrols, i uesd as datatype in my pages(my controls are derived from `umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper.IUsercontrolDataEditor`).

so steps i have to do to upgrade Umbraco and keep my site running normal.

Comment: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/

Answer (score 2):

I have upgraded between similar versions before by overwriting the /bin files and deleting the stuff like umbraco.config & examine indexes that get rebuilt when they are deleted.

The official site has a version specific upgrade path that seems logical enough: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/Upgrading/version-specific

But, I'd question why you would upgrade from 4.5 to 4.11 - as Niels Hartvig has often stated, there is no real upgrade path, its just a series of overwrites and deleting what gets deprecated.  I guess you're looking for razor support - but with v7 imminent I'm not sure that an upgrade within the v4 family of releases has a long enough life span to justify it.  Why not stick with v4.5 until you're ready to completely rewrite in MVC in v6 or v7?